# Karma Cannot find names

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, es6-promise

I'm trying to run unit test with karma but throw some errors and I think that it's because of ES6. I'm using:

- Typescript
- Jasmine
- Karma

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "wep-backend",
  "version": "3.0.0-alfa",
  "description": "Back-end API ",
  "main": "./src/server/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tsc && karma start",
    "debug": "tsc && npm run build.debug && gulp copy && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run nodemon:debug \" ",
    "prod": "tsc && npm run build.prod && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run nodemon:w\" ",
    "staging": "tsc && npm run build.staging && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run nodemon:w\" ",
    "start": "tsc && npm run build.dev && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run nodemon:w\" ",
    "nodemon:w": "nodemon --config",
    "nodemon:debug": "nodemon --exec ts-node --debug src/server/index.ts",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "build.dev": "gulp dev",
    "build.staging": "gulp staging",
    "build.prod": "gulp prod",
    "build.debug": "gulp debug"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@git.netlogistik.com:wep/backend.git"
  },
  "author": "Netlogistik",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dateformat": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.37",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "dateformat": "^1.0.12",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "inversify": "^2.0.1",
    "inversify-express-utils": "^2.0.2",
    "knex": "^0.11.10",
    "lodash": "^4.16.5",
    "mssql": "^3.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.0.35",
    "@types/body-parser": "^0.0.33",
    "@types/dotenv": "^2.0.18",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.33",
    "@types/gulp": "^3.8.32",
    "@types/inversify": "^2.0.31",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/knex": "0.0.35",
    "@types/mssql": "^3.1.29",
    "@types/sinon": "^1.16.31",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-file": "^0.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-es6-shim": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6",
    "ts-node": "^1.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

My karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    frameworks: ["jasmine", "karma-typescript", "sinon", "es6-shim"],

    files: [
      { pattern: "src/server/ws/**/*.ts" }
    ],

    exclude: [
      "src/server/ws/**/*.controller.ts",
      "src/server/ws/**/*.repository.ts"
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      "src/server/ws/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript", "coverage"]
    },

    reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript", "coverage"],

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        {
          type: "text-summary"
        },
        {
          type: "html",
          dir: "coverage/"
        }
      ]
    },

    browsers: ["Chrome"]
  });
};
```

And those are some errors that throw the compiler

```
06 01 2017 17:18:04.887:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.controller.ts(180,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.887:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.controller.ts(210,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.887:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(23,69): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.887:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(24,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.887:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(25,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(45,26): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(81,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(82,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(83,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(88,22): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(102,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(104,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.888:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(106,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.889:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(114,22): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.889:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(119,51): error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'User[]'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.890:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(161,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.891:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(162,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.891:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(164,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.891:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(171,22): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.891:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(208,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.892:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(209,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.892:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(211,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.892:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(214,22): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.893:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(230,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.893:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(231,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.894:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(233,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.894:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(241,26): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.894:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(262,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.894:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(263,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.894:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(265,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.894:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(268,22): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.894:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(285,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.895:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(286,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.896:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(288,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

06 01 2017 17:18:04.896:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]: src/server/ws/user/user.repository.ts(296,26): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'QueryBuilder'.

06 01 2017 17:18:05.572:INFO [compiler.karma-typescript]: Compiled 118 files in 3409 ms.
06 01 2017 17:18:06.529:INFO [builtin-bundler.karma-typescript]: Bundled imports for 69 file(s) in 380 ms.
06 01 2017 17:18:07.446:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
06 01 2017 17:18:07.454:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
06 01 2017 17:18:07.454:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
06 01 2017 17:18:07.506:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
06 01 2017 17:18:09.530:INFO [Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.12.2)]: Connected on socket /#Q5le2XaT3wVYNPqcAAAA with id 2301486
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.12.2) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Not found: /Users/raansilrey/WebstormProjects/wep-backend/src/server/constants/types.ts
  at node_modules/karma-typescript/lib/bundlers/builtin/commonjs.js:15
```

Could anyone to help me?

Thanks.